# Why my github page can't redirect to my custom domain?

Tags: dns, jekyll, blogs, github-pages

I set the DNS and github shown in the pictures

- DNS:
  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Nf04.png]
- GitHub:
  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNdmK.png]

But when enter my custom domain eletroweak.me, I still can't get my github pages, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

First, your GitHub repo is [github.com/NewTanc/NewTanc.github.io](https://github.com/NewTanc/NewTanc.github.io), which means your GitHub pages URL would be https://NewTanc.github.io, not `newtanc.github.io`: this is case sensitive.

Second, `newtanc.github.io` redirects to `eletroweak.me`, where it should be the reverse.
See "[Setting up an apex domain](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/)" and "[Configuring `A` records with your DNS provider](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-an-apex-domain/#configuring-a-records-with-your-dns-provider)".